# Rails .json.jbuilder refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic index.json.jbuilder file in clients/index.json.jbuilder:

```
json.array!(@clientsAPI) do |client|
  json.extract! client, :year, :business_name
end
```

When I submit a form in my view, the `@clientsAPI` is updated in the index method of the clients_controller. However, the index.json.jbuilder does not get updated, and leaves the old `@clientsAPI` values (before form submit).

How can I get `@clientsAPI` to get updated in index.json.jbuilder upon form refresh?

clients_controlled code:

```
def index
        @clients = Client.all

        begin
          @year_filter = params[:c][:year]
        rescue 
          @year_filter = ["2016"]
        end

        @clientsAPI = @clients.where(year:@year_filter)

        render 'index'
end
```

clients/index.html.erb form routed to the index method shown above:

```
<%= form_for :c, url:clients_path, method: :get" do |f| %>    
  <%= f.select :year, options_for_select(@years),{onchange: "this.form.submit();"} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What action does your form submit to (create/update etc)? Could you show the controller code for that action, and the corresponding create.json.jbuilder/update.json.jbuilder - I am guessing that there is not a `@clientsAPI` variable being set in that action.

Comment: I added the controller code. The form is routed to do a `GET` request to the index method. Everything within Rails updates just fine, but for some reason the @clientsAPI in the index.json.jbuilder doesn't get updated when the form submits. Any ideas what to look into here? Is the jbuilder supposed to update on form submission?

Comment: Is your form submitting a json request or html? It will need to submit with `format: 'json'` and then you have to make sure you respond to the json format in you controller: `respond_to do |format| ...etc`. I am not sure what your `export_grid_if_requested` block does, but if you are getting to there is will only render the html response and not the index.json.jbuilder

Comment: I took out the `export_grid_if_requested` so now it always hits the `render index` Also, I showed the get request form. Would you mind posting an answer on how to `render index` and refresh the index.json.jbuilder `@clientsAPI` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but should hopefully get you close enough..

In your form_for, you need to tell it to submit a json request. Something like:

```
<%= form_for :c, url:clients_path(format: 'json'), method: :get" do |f| %>
```

then in your index method, respond to the json request:

```
def index
    @clients = Client.all

    begin
      @year_filter = params[:c][:year]
    rescue 
      @year_filter = ["2016"]
    end

    @clientsAPI = @clients.where(year:@year_filter)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
       render 'index'
       }
      format.json {
       #any logic here specific to a json request.
       #doing nothing will render index.json.jbuilder by default
       }
    end
```

end

Comment: So, that is close. But it always renders the json response then. I need it to render both the json and the index. Do you know how to render both?

Comment: What is it you need to do with both the html and the json response? I don't think rails is really designed to render multiple responses from a single request. There should be away to do what you need with one format or the other

Comment: I have an angular table within the view that reads the .json response and displays data. That same view also displays charts that are in rails. So, I am trying to display the updated info in both the rails charts and the angular table.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that you display any html from rails, and then once angular is loaded, get angular to do a json request (using the angular $http service), to get the json object and load it into the appropriate angular scope variable.

Comment: That is actually exactly what the table is doing. For some reason though, when angular does the $http request, the `@clientsAPI` variable in jbuilder is not updated with the latest params from the form. So, the controller logic run through, updates rails data, but the angular data remains the same.. any ideas?

Comment: For some reason the jbuilder gets ignored when the controller updates, unless I specifically render the .json response.

Comment: could you show your $http code that call that makes the request?

Comment: `return $http.get('/clients.json').success(function(data){ angular.copy(data, o.posts); });`

Comment: Do you think angular isn't refreshing, or the clients.json not refreshing unless I specifically render it instead of the `render index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125458/discussion-between-mahi-man-and-hoosiercoder).